# Ideal shape for underwater habitat

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Is there an analytic solution to this problem or do I need to compute a discrete approximation using a relaxation procedure - or something similar?

I want to find the shape of a roughly spherical shell, which, when submerged in a liquid medium of density *d*, will experience no bending moments at any point on its surface. At depths much larger than the maximum dimension of the shell, the ideal shape approaches a sphere, but I am interested in the case of a relatively shallow submersion for an underwater habitat at atmospheric pressure.

Another way to describe this shape is that it is the same as the shape assumed by a small drop of liquid on a non-wetting surface - except for the flat portion against that surface. To better understand the dynamics of the situation, consider a pool of mercury on a flat, level piece of glass. If you put this in a chamber with a viewport and increase the air pressure in the chamber, you will see that the mercury will assume a shape that takes up less volume until  the sum of the gravitational potential of the mercury and the potential energy of the compressed gas is at a minimum. The mercury will take up less volume to do this and thereby assume a more nearly spherical shape.

I read a paper on this a long time ago, but I haven't been able to find it again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your analogy. A drop of liquid typically does not change its volume -- do you mean its surface area? Also, if the external air pressure is uniform it does not influence the shape of an incompressible drop, because the work done against a uniform pressure field depends only on the change in volume.

Comment: You are right. The volume does not change. The ratio of suface area to volume changes. In order for this ratio to change, the shape must change. I see your point, though. I'll have to think this through.

Comment: I think it must be that the uniform pressure field and uniform surface tension field are somehow coupled. I'm still grappling with the issue, though.

Comment: If the increasing uniform pressure field is simply added to the constant uniform surface tension field, that would seem to explain why the mercury approaches a sphere in shape. It has the same effect as increasing the surface tension would.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is no analytics solution to this problem. I finally found the paper in my files, that I couldn't find when I posted this question. For the benefit of anyone interested in this problem, I refer them to:

Royles, R; A. B. Sofoluwe; M. M. Baig; and A. J. Currie. "Behaviour of Underwater Enclosures of Optimum Design." Strain 16(1):12–20 (1980)